# scroll box not working/ making a relative positioned element disappear under a fixed element when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner at web design and I am having trouble making a scroll box work. I am trying to have a relative position element be able to be scrolled with a fixed header(navigation bar) and the relative element to go underneath or 'disappear' once it's scrolled up.

```
<html>
<style> 

.toplinks{
position:fixed;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top:70px;
margin-left:300px;
padding:0;
font-size: 18px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
display: block;
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#paragraph{
font-size: 15px;
position:relative;
overflow:auto;
width:65%;
height:30%;
top:250px;
left:250px;
z-index:-3;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="toplinks">
<ui> <li> link</li>
<li><link</li>
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li></div>

<div id="paragraph"> heres a block of text that will probably also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a number of things in your code that are incorrect and/or not necessary. For example, it's `<ul>` not `<ui>` and you need a closing tag. This isn't going to solve your problem but just want you to be aware. If you can post a link to a website that has the functionality you are looking for, I can help you but with the code you have, you'll need to start over.

Comment: well take youtube for example. you scroll and the videos in the feed all go up and kind of disappear behind the navigation bar? if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

@Jamie Theophilos

First of all there are number of issues with your code, like you haven't closed the **ul** tag, also using a **<** under a **li** tag

Just do that rest your **CSS** and **Html** is fine. You can also check this URL that works fine with you own code: **https://jsfiddle.net/itskamalkumar/zr9aLcz9/**

**Html**

```
<div class="toplinks">
<ul>
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="paragraph"> heres a block of text that will probably also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed heres a block of text that will probably also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed heres a block of text that will probably also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed heres a block of text that will probably also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed heres a block of text that will probably also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed heres a block of text that will probably also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed heres a block of text that will probably also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed heres a block of text that will probably also
have a picture that I want to be able to be scrollable with 
the navigation bar up top fixed</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.toplinks{
position:fixed;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top:70px;
margin-left:150px;
padding:0;
font-size: 18px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
display: block;
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#paragraph{
font-size: 15px;
position:relative;
overflow:auto;
width:65%;
height:30%;
top:250px;
left:150px;
z-index:-3;
}
```